# Use DHCP-provided DNS or not based on connected network

Tags: linux, dns, networkmanager, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

My current networking setup (on Arch Linux) involves:

- [stubby](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Stubby) to resolve DNS requests with DNS-over-TLS.
- [dnsmasq](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dnsmasq) to cache DNS queries (and nothing else).
- [openresolv](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openresolv) to manage `resolv.conf`.
- [NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager) to set-up and tear-down network connections.

I have *stubby* listening on `locahost` on some random port, *dnsmasq* listening on `localhost:53` and resolving DNS queries through *stubby*, and *openresolv* is set up to put `localhost` in `resolv.conf` and provide any other DNS entry (for example those obtained through DHCP by NetworkManager) to *dnsmasq* via separate configuration files:

```
# /etc/resolvconf.conf
name_servers=127.0.0.1

dnsmasq_conf=/etc/dnsmasq-conf.conf
dnsmasq_resolv=/etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf
```

However, at the moment those extra entries are being ignored.

> What is the best way to use these entries only when connected to one of a few whitelisted networks?

To clarify, I know that with NetworkManager I can override the DNS entries provided over DHCP on a network-by-network basis, but what I would like to do is the opposite: use *stubby* by default and the DHCP entries for only one or two networks, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkManager can create a custom zone per Wireless network see:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/configuring_and_managing_networking/index

Section 9.2. Configuring a Wi-Fi connection using nmcli